# Building XML file using python pandas to_xml

Tags: python, pandas, xml

**I'm building an xml data structure using the following python code:**

```
pl = pd.read_sql(sql2, cnxn)
Input_data_in_xml = str(pl.to_xml(index=False, root_name='Root', row_name='Row', 
                        xml_declaration=False, encoding='utf-8'))

   print(Input_data_in_xml)
```

**this produces an output as follows**

```
<Root>
    <Row>
      <element1>value</element1>
      <element2>value</element2>
      <element3>value</element3>
      <element4>value</element4>
      <subelement5>value</subelement5>
      <subelement6>value</subelement6>
      <subelement7>value</subelement7>
      <subelement8>value</subelement8>
    </Row>
<Root>
```

**I need the output to look like the below**

```
<Root>
    <Row>
      <element1>value</element1>
      <element2>value</element2>
      <element3>value</element3>
      <element4>
        <f id="subelement5">value</f>
        <f id="subelement6">value</f>
        <f id="subelement7">value</f>
        <f id="subelement8">value</f>
      </element4>
    </Row>
<Root>
```

**I've started to build a solution using lxml but have run into a new error**

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql2, cnxn)

header = df.columns

root = ET.Element('root')  # Root element

for column in df.columns:
    entry = ET.SubElement(root, column)  # Adding element
    for row in df.index:
        schild = row
        child = ET.SubElement(entry, schild)  # Adding sub-element
        child.text = str(df[column][schild])

xml_data = ET.tostring(root)  # binary string
print(xml_data)
```

**Error Message**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Verint\test.py", line 132, in <module>
    xml_data = ET.tostring(root)  # binary string
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1109, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(stream, encoding,
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 746, in write
    qnames, namespaces = _namespaces(self._root, default_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 849, in _namespaces
    for elem in elem.iter():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iter'
```

Comment: *building xml* is the goal. *using pandas* is a tool. why not consider other tools(lxml for example)?

Comment: that is a good point...do you have a reference site you would recommend?

Comment: The line of code in the traceback differs from the same line in the code sample you gave us. Ignoring comments, this line appears as `xml_data = ET.tostring(str(root))` in the traceback, but  `xml_data = ET.tostring(root)`. The latter line lacks the call to `str`, and I can certainly imagine this call causing the error you get.

Comment: good catch i was testing solutions but was still getting the same error. i've updated the traceback to reflect the code shown